# Equivalência ao kmeans dentro do caret::train

Tags: r, machine-learning

Tentei ajustar um modelo `kmeans` dentro do *package* `caret` com a função `train`. Mas verifiquei que ele não está disponível. Gerei um frame qualquer para fazer isso:

```
set.seed(15)

d <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(6, rnorm(10000, 1000, 125))
)

cluster <- kmeans(d, centers = 3)
cluster

d$grupo <- as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])

library(recipes)
library(caret)

r <- recipe(grupo ~ ., data = d)
p <- prep(r, d)
b <- bake(p, d)

t <- train(
  r, 
  d, 
  method = 'kmeans', 
  trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 3)
)
```

> Error: Model kmeans is not in caret's built-in library

- Há alguma função equivalente a `kmeans` para que eu possa fazer a validação do modelo?

Ajustei com uma `lda` e foi ok, mas, gostaria de uma orientação referente ao `kmeans`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`caret` é a sigla para **C**lassification **A**nd **RE**gression **T**raining. Por definição, é um pacote que disponibiliza algoritmos para classificação e regressão de dados.

Classificação é como chamamos um método capaz de separar nossas observações de acordo com classes já pré-definidas. É o que se chama de aprendizagem supervisionada. Vários métodos de classificação estão disponíveis no `caret`, como LDA, Random Forest, K Vizinhos Mais Próximos e similares. [Neste link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) está a lista completa destes métodos.

Clusterização é como chamamos um método capaz de separar nossas observações sem  necessidade de utilizar classes pré-definidas. É o que se chama de aprendizagem não-supervisionada.

K-means é um método de clusterização. Portanto, não está disponível para o `caret`. Provavelmente, nunca estará.

Portanto, a resposta para a pergunta

> Há alguma função equivalente a kmeans para que eu possa fazer a validação do modelo?

é **não**, não há função equivalente a `kmeans` no `caret`. Ele é um pacote que faz classificação, não clusterização.

Entretanto, é possível usar K Means como um classificador. Até onde sei, não existe uma opção pra isso já pronta no `R`, mas nada te impede de programar a tua. Eu não recomendaria isso, pois o K Means tem sérios problemas, como

1. Não funciona bem em dados com muitas dimensões
2. Não funciona se os grupos tem tamanhos muito discrepantes entre si
3. Como ele utiliza a distância euclidiana para decidir o pertencimento de observações aos grupos, não vai funcionar bem para dados com assimetrias grandes ou muitos outliers

Por outro lado, me parece que o teu problema é algo relacionado à classificação, pois tu tem acesso às classes de cada observação. Portanto, qualquer método de classificação do `caret` serviria para treinar e validar a tua modelagem. Se eu entendi corretamente e o teu problema é de classificação e não clusterização, sugiro que desista do K Means e parta para algo mais sofisticado.